# Why am I able to load Contacts from my Android phone with the Cordova Contact API but not on ios?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm building a cross platform phone app using dhtml and steroids.js which is built on top of Phonegap. I'm trying to use the Cordova [Contact](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts) API to load Contacts from my phone into an ul element. Here is the code I have inside of my head tags. It works fine when I load my app on my Android device but not on an iphone4 or 5.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 // Wait for Cordova to load
 //
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
// find all contacts
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter=""; 
options.multiple=true;
var filter = ["*"];
navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
//
function onSuccess(contacts) {

for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
//alert(contacts[i].displayName);

var mycontact = contacts[i].displayName;
alert(mycontact);

//Just making sure if a contact is null, it won't be appended to the ul. 
if(mycontact == null){
}   
else
{
// Using a little jQuery to append to contacts to the ul
$("#contactlist").append('<li style="background-color:rgb (184,249,255);height:70px;overflow:hidden;border-top:solid 1px; border-bottom:solid 1px background-color:rgb(184,249,255);"><p style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 18px;top: 5px;position:   relative;left: 10px;">' + mycontact + '</p></li>');
  }

 }

 // ele.innerHTML = str;
 }

// onError: Failed to get the contacts
//
function onError(contactError) {
alert('onError!');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using `filter = ["*"]` doesn't actually return all contact fields. Try explicitly declaring which fields you want to return, e.g. `filter = ["displayName", "phoneNumbers"]`.

It seems like this is a Cordova issue, but I was unable to quickly locate anything to back my assumption.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work :( I'm actually trying to get phone numbers now and I'm unable to